# How can I export data to google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, automation

Hey guys I've made a scraping programm that scrapes some info from  websites and now I need to throw that info into a google sheet I was wondering what's the best way? to convert it into a csv file then throw it in sheets? or anything else I am open to suggestions .

Comment: Start by reading through the docs at https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python

Comment: You want to create a new sheet or update an existing one? What is the type and structure of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Using [google APIs](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python) is the better way do it, Where you avoid resource intensive file read/write operation.

Pre-req: create a service account and have the key json handy, here is the sample code in python:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import datetime

SCOPE = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'xxxxxx'

def update_cell(cell, value):
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('downloaded.json', SCOPE)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open_by_key(SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID).get_worksheet(1)
wks.update_acell(cell, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_cell('A1', 'test')
```

Comment: when I do this there's an error by pylint saying  invalid syntax on  the credentials line  what can I do about that? I tried googling it but couldn't find an asnwer

Comment: Works fine for me (python 2.7) Could you please post your error

Answer (score 0):

Publish a google sheet and you can access it like any other REST api.

Check this for reference:

[Access google sheets through python](https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2)